# Repeating actions on state with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, kotlin, rx-kotlin

This is in Kotlin, but I think anyone who writes Java will be able to understand.

I'm trying to make a stopwatch with Rx and I'm having a little trouble with doing the actual stopping and starting. The big problem is that I don't know how to keep the current time, while modifying it as different actions (starting and stopping) come in. Here's what I've got right now.

```
fullTime.switchMap { startTime ->
    controlCommands.switchMap { command ->
        when (command) {
            ControlState.PLAY -> Observable.interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map {
                ControlState.PLAY
            }
            ControlState.PAUSE -> Observable.just(ControlState.PAUSE)
            else -> Observable.just(ControlState.STOP)
        }
    }
}
```

Where `fullTime` and `controlCommands` are `Observable`s that emit events about the current starting time to count down from and say what to do next, respectively. I want to chain off of `controlCommands` and be able to keep state starting at `startTime` that will count down when a `PLAY` event appears, pause when `PAUSE` appears, and reset at `startTime` when `STOP` appears.

`scan` almost works, but I don't know how to stop after the timer hits 0 and `PLAY` is still being sent every second, since it would be sending duplicate info. Also it doesn't allow a separation between the state and the observed value. So the value I accumulate with `scan` has to be the same type as the value inside the `Observable` (if that makes sense).

Any ideas what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are on the right track with `scan`. You just need

- a `.takeUntil(state -> state.hasCompleted)` to stop when you need to stop (ow maybe a `takeWhile`, it depends).
- then a `.map(state -> state.getValute())` to get the value

Does this make sense?

Comment: Will that cause the subscription to complete, or will it continue if a new command / time comes in?

Comment: `.takeUntil` will cause the subscription to terminate - it will unsubcribe from the parent when the condition is met.

Comment: So this isn't really what I want then, since I want to continue observing `fullTime` and `controlCommands`.

Comment: Hmmm - ok, can you produce a marble diagram that shows your usecase? I don't think I understand your requirements.

Comment: I want `fullTime` and `controlCommands` to always be emitting things, as they come from the UI. Really what I'm asking is how can I pause the `interval` with knowledge from downstream (the `scan`). When the scan result hits zero, I want to stop ticking on the `interval` and just use the zero. My attempt right now is to just use `distinctUntilChanged` which I think will work for this case.